# iOS streaming video in webview or MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, streaming

I have to stream video (.mov) from server.
I use a UIWebView and it works well but the delegate method

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

is always call instead

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

I print the error:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=204 "Plug-in handled load" (...)
```

Afterwards I decided to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead.
It looks more slow!
It's a good practice use UIWebView for streaming videos? How can I fix my error?
Are there any fastes solutions for my purpose?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Again if you are decided to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Try this...

```
-(IBAction)btnVideoClicked:(id)sender
{
    @try 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        GetVideos *obj_video = [arrVideos objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj_video.VideoPath]];
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        [moviePlayerViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
        // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStateDidChange:)      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification    object:moviePlayerViewController];
        // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification     object:moviePlayerViewController];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
        moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [moviePlayerViewController release];
        [pool release];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // throws exception
    }
}
```